# How do I set up permissions for an Azure Application so that an application can access a site and its drives?

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api

First time working with the Microsoft Graph API and ran into something I'm not too sure about.

I'm supposed to be building some proof of concept web app where I can basically view a business drive (or a site/group drive) from an application (with it's own identity) and upload/download files to it. However, I'm running into some issues with figuring out what I'm doing wrong.

I wrote some helper functions to help me get a token, but it just doesn't seem to work.

Here are the functions I wrote:

```
public static async Task<string> GetAccessToken() {

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(tokenUrl);
        // We want the response to be JSON.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        // Build up the data to POST.
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"));
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", clientId));
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", clientSecret));
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", scope));
        FormUrlEncodedContent requestBody = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
        //Request Token
        var request = await client.PostAsync(tokenUrl, requestBody).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var response = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
        //Return Token
        return ((dynamic)responseData).access_token;
    }
}

public static async Task<dynamic> GetSite(string accessToken) {

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        // Add the Authorization header with the AccessToken.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        // create the URL string.
        string url = string.Format("{0}sites/root/", baseUrl);
        // make the request
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
        // parse the response and return the data.
        string jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        object responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
        return (dynamic)responseData;
    }
}
```

Whenever I would try to get a site, it seems to not work properly. So I figured I could try out the requests in Postman to see if they would work there, but after [setting up Postman for application API calls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman#set-up-application-api-calls), the response I would usually get is something like this:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "generalException",
    "message": "An unspecified error has occurred.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "SomeTimeLateAtNight",
      "request-id": "WhateverTheRequestIDis",
      "client-request-id": "WhateverTheClientRequestIDis"
    }
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here? In my App Registration, I have the API Permissions set to `"Sites.ReadAll, Sites.ReadWriteAll"`, which I found from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). I ran my token through [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) and found that my roles were set to:

```
"APIConnectors.ReadWrite.All", "Sites.Selected", "Directory.ReadWrite.All", "Sites.Read.All", "Sites.ReadWrite.All", "Sites.Manage.All", "Files.ReadWrite.All", "Directory.Read.All", "Files.Read.All", "APIConnectors.Read.All", "Sites.FullControl.All"
```

These should be what I need to read/write/view these right? So I'm left a bit confused.

Just for kicks, I tried doing my requests through the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), but everything ends up working as expected. I also pulled the auth token from the Graph Explorer request I did, and shoved it into my Postman requests and it ended up working, which leads me to believe I screwed up something with the Azure Application API permissions somehow. Any recommendations on where to go from here? Not sure if I'm explaining clearly enough, but how should I fix it so that requests as the application get an actual result instead of that general exception I'm getting? (Since the application would download/upload as itself, without any other user logged in.)

Comment: By "site" are you referring to Azure App Services? If so, then sorry, but App Services' filesystems cannot be accessed except via Kudu.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "business drive"? Are you referring to Azure Files (where a filesystem is exposed as an SMB share to Azure VMs) or OneDrive-for-Business or something else?

Comment: @Dai Thanks for the quick reply! For 'site' I was referring to something like a sharepoint site or a group site, but the Application I set up is on Azure App Services. As for "business drive", I was referring to OneDrive. To better clarify what I'm trying to do, I'm trying to sync a drive (a onedrive directory I guess) to another directory (whether it be on some server or locally).

Comment: @andrewterry What is the tokenurl and baseUrl that you are using?

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity For the tokenURL, I was using "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenantID]/oauth2/v2.0/token/". For the baseURL, I was using "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/".

Comment: @andrewterry I guess what StanleyGong suggested will work

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity I also wanted to point out that my permissions do have Admin consent to them, similar to what StanleyGong posted (since they also have a green checkmark next to them)

Answer (score 0):

I created a new Azure AD App for your code for a quick test, these are the permissions that I granted to my app,please make sure that you have clicked the "Grant admin consent for" button to finish the grant permission process:

[image]

My test code below, based on a console app:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GraphAPITest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var accessToken = GetAccessToken().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            Console.WriteLine(GetSite(accessToken).GetAwaiter().GetResult());
        }



        public static async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
        {

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var clientId = "<app id>"; 
                var clientSecret = "<secret>";
                var tenant = "<your tenant name/id>";

                var scope = @"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";
                var tokenUrl = @"https://login.microsoftonline.com/"+ tenant + "/oauth2/v2.0/token";
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(tokenUrl);
                // We want the response to be JSON.
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                // Build up the data to POST.
                List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"));
                postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", clientId));
                postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", clientSecret));
                postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", scope));
                FormUrlEncodedContent requestBody = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
                //Request Token
                var request = await client.PostAsync(tokenUrl, requestBody).ConfigureAwait(false);
                var response = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
                //Return Token
                return ((dynamic)responseData).access_token;
            }
        }

        public static async Task<dynamic> GetSite(string accessToken)
        {

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var baseUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/";
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                // Add the Authorization header with the AccessToken.
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
                // create the URL string.
                string url = string.Format("{0}sites/root/", baseUrl);
                 

   // make the request
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
                // parse the response and return the data.
                string jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                object responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
                return (dynamic)responseData;
            }
        }
    }

    
}
```

Result:

[image]

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the permission type application or delegated.

[image]

If it is application permission, the status column for the respective permission - green

[image]

If you see a warning message - meaning that the Admin consent has not been granted. You will have to get the consent before using the app. This error is likely the case.

Answer (score 0):

You may have added the necessary permissions but forgot to provide the 'admin consent' as identified by Satya. Additional I would recommend using the MSAL library from Microsoft to handle this flow like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-netcore-daemon
Considerably fewer lines of more readable code.